# condition-> change text of <p>

Tags: jquery, html

I found all the images that their `src` is not: "delete.png" and change their image to be "active.png":

```
$("img.sign[src!='delete.png']").attr({ 'src': 'active.png', 'alt': 'Active' });
```

If I changed an image, I want to change also the text of the `<p>` below it to be 'Active'.

**Before:**

```
<td class="TableTD">
<p style="display:inline;" class="yellow" title="<p style='margin-top:0px;font-
size:12px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px'>Active</p>">
<img alt="Active" src="active.png" class="sign"/>
</p></td>

<td class="TableTD">
<p style="display:inline;" class="yellow" title="<p style='margin-top:0px;font-
size:12px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px'>Pause</p>">
<img alt="Pause" src="pause.png" class="sign"/>
</p></td>

<td class="TableTD">
<p style="display:inline;" class="yellow" title="<p style='margin-top:0px;font-
size:12px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px'>Delete</p>">
<img alt="Delete" src="delete.png" class="sign"/>
</p></td>
```

**After:**

```
<td class="TableTD">
<p style="display:inline;" class="yellow" title="<p style='margin-top:0px;font-
size:12px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px'>Active</p>">
<img alt="Active" src="active.png" class="sign"/>
</p></td>

<td class="TableTD">
<p style="display:inline;" class="yellow" title="<p style='margin-top:0px;font-
size:12px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px'>Active</p>">
<img alt="Active" src="active.png" class="sign"/>
</p></td>

<td class="TableTD">
<p style="display:inline;" class="yellow" title="<p style='margin-top:0px;font-
size:12px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px'>Delete</p>">
<img alt="Delete" src="delete.png" class="sign"/>
</p></td>
```

I thought to write something like:

```
$("td.TableTd p").innerHTML = 'Active'
```

but it will change the last td..

**UPDATE:**

For example:

```
<p style="display:inline;" class="yellow" title="<p style='margin-top:0px;font-
size:12px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px'>Pause</p>">
```

I want to change the word: `Pause` to be `Active`

Comment: Why have you got HTML in your `title` attributes? if they're to help style a pop-up/modal, consider putting the styles/classes in your stylesheet (it would be far more maintainable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *" I want to change also the text of the `<p>` below it to be 'Active'"*

When you say "the `<p>` below it" you seem to be talking about the text within the `title` attribute of the parent `<p>`. (I assume you're using some sort of tooltip plugin that turns the content of that `title` into real elements on hover.) If so you can do this:

```
$("img.sign[src!='delete.png']").attr({
    'src': 'active.png', 'alt': 'Active'
}).closest('p').attr('title', function(i, oldVal) {
    return oldVal.replace(/>[^<]*</, '>Active<');
});
```

(As a general rule it's not a good plan to parse html with regexes, but in this specific case it should be safe enough.)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CT6wU/

Comment: Your example (including your update) would be easier to follow if you didn't have to scroll right to see it, or if you explicitly stated that you're talking about changing text within the `title` attribute, but in any case my interpretation of your original question seems to be correct - I believe my code does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('img.sign[src!="delete.png"]').attr({'src': 'active.png', 'alt': 'Active' }).parent('p').attr('title', '<p style="margin-top:0px;font-size:12px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px">Active</p>');
```

Comment: But `.prev()` selects siblings. The img element is a child of the p.

Comment: His HTML markup is malformed, there's a missing `<p>` start tag I think... Fixed it back. Sorry it was all just confusing =)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$("img.sign[src!='delete.png']").
            parent('p').title = 
                '<p style="margin-top:0px;font-size:12px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px">Active</p>'
```

Comment: This will set a `title` property on the jQuery object returned from `parent('p')`, _not_ on the DOM element(s) within that jQuery object.

Comment: sure, but the title contain the other P element. Iøm just replacing the all P in the title same way as he set it in the first place

Comment: I'm not sure how to say this more clearly. Your code is _not_ setting the title attribute of any p elements. You are creating a title property on the jQuery object and leaving all of the p elements unchanged. You need to say _...parent('p').attr('title', ..._ rather than _...parent('p').title = ..._

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var item = $("img.sign[src!='delete.png']");
    item.attr({ 'src': 'active.png', 'alt': 'Active' });
    alert(item.parent());
    item.parent().attr("title", "<p style='margin-top:0px;font-size:12px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px'>Active</p>")
});
```